# How do I choose a database?

Tags: sql, database

I need a comparison table of some sort for database varieties (MySQL, SQLite etc.). I can't find one.

My use case is, I am implementing storage of objects in a distributed hash table. I need a database solution that is:

- Fast for sorting
- Simplistic (no users, preferably no additional structures like multiple tables etc.)
- Concurrent (if possible)
- Multi-platform
- File based (not stored in memory primarily)
- Centralized

I will be programming in Go.

As I understand, I believe I need what is called a **Document Orientated Database**, because I am storing objects, identified by keys.

**EDIT:** While I am implementing a DHT, I will also be storing metadata about the objects, such as access counts etc. It would also be preferable to have TLL (time to live)

Comment: Tables are not exactly "object-orientated things"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Document oriented" isn't what I would call what you want.  I think you want a "key-value store," which is probably the simplest type of NoSQL to use.  You can do something like this:

```
> set "key" value
"OK"
> get "key"
"value"
```

As such, I recommend [redis](http://redis.io), which I find pleasantly "light" compared to the heavier and more structured alternatives.  You can try it at [Try Redis](http://try.redis-db.com/), which is a functional interactive shell.

---

**Edit**: your comment, as well as your edit, continue to recommend Redis.  Redis has TTL, in the form of two commands: `expire`, which takes a number of seconds, and `expireat`, which takes a Unix timestamp.  In addition, it allows hashes, which meet your needs (as I understand them):

```
> hmset POST:dd68f250-c3f2-11e1-9b21-0800200c9a66 _timestamp 1341198420 title "An Example" content "This is an example of a representation of a blog post (or something) in Redis."
"OK"
> hgetall POST:dd68f250-c3f2-11e1-9b21-0800200c9a66
{"_timestamp":"1341198420","title":"An Example","content":"This is an example of a representation of a blog post (or something) in Redis."}
> expire POST:dd68f250-c3f2-11e1-9b21-0800200c9a66 60
true
> ttl POST:dd68f250-c3f2-11e1-9b21-0800200c9a66
53
```

Comment: You can store a hash in Redis as well, which allows you to have multiple keys associated with one "object."

Comment: I like Redis, just a few more questions. In one of my use cases, I need to get the 20 closest objects to a key. Distance is defined as the XOR of two keys (Kademlia).
This would require some sorting by a custom algorithm (XOR metric of each object key on the key). How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: I haven't done this specifically myself; that hasn't been something that I needed to do.  I think the built-in Lua scripting (http://redis.io/commands/eval) would be able to do this for you server-side, although I'm not certain.

Comment: Actually, it looks like 2.6 also includes a `bitop` command.  I think you could use this pretty easily with the Lua scripting to get what you need.

Comment: I want to do this in pseudo-code:  

**"SORT objects BY (# XOR key) LIMIT 20"**

 where objects is the list of keys, and # is the special pattern mentioned here - http://redis.io/commands/sort). I'm really confused as to how I would do this in Redis. I haven't been able to find any way to sort by a value that is different for each element.